# How do i navigate to another jspx?

Tags: html, jsp, jspx

I have a link on a jspx, which will take you to another jspx page.
For example, i'm on the homepage and then click on a link which should open a jspx called products.
I have used this code

```
<a href="products">View all products</a>
```

but it doesn't work. How would i do this?

Answer (score 0):

The `href` should point to an actual page itself (using a valid URL), such as `products.jspx`.

**Example:**

```
<a href="products.jspx">View All Products</a>
```

**If your products page is within another folder:**

```
<a href="folder/products.jspx">View All Products</a>
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that i have tried that but it does not work

Comment: Do you have a page that is called "products.jspx"? Or is it within a folder, as you may have to include additional pathing information. I'll edit my example.

Comment: products.jspx is in web pages folder.
When i run it, it displays http status 500

Comment: You will need to put a relative path from where the current page is to your target page, for example: If the location of your current page has a folder named "web_pages" and within that folder is your page "products.jspx", you would need to reference it as such:

<a href="web_pages/products.jspx">View All Products</a>

Alternatively, you could simply try moving your products.jspx page into the same location as your current page and use:

<a href="products.jspx">View All Products</a>

Comment: it is in the same location, i have tried adding /web/products.jspx and it still does not work

Comment: If the products.jspx is in the same location as your current page, (for example's sake, index.jspx), then you would only need to use <a href="products.jspx">

Comment: no, i am using a model-view-controller. i have found that "../products.jspx" works but if i click it twice, it does up another level and i get a 404 code

Comment: Ah - I didn't know it was using MVC - have you tried just a <a href='/products'>

Comment: I have found that <a href="../products.jspx> works but if i click it twice it comes up with error page 404. 
I get this when i first login. "http://localhost:8084/shop/do/login". This shows the page product page. When i click the products link in the navigation bar, it becomes http://localhost:8084/shop/viewAll.jspx but it still displays the page however when i click it again, i get a 404 error.

Comment: If you remove change the "../products.jspx" to something like "Controller/Products" or "Controller/Products.jspx", maybe some of those might fix your issue. The relative pathing (..) will cause it to continue to backtrack and eventually you would be unable to find your target.

Comment: i have tried that but it gives me a error 500, nullpointer exception

Comment: Is it possible that you are only changing the navigation URL in a single page? So that when you navigate to another one it uses a different URL to direct to?

Comment: I have created a navigation.jspx which contains the links to the various jspx pages. I include the navigation in every page via <jsp:include page="navigation.jspx"/>