# Navigating from 1 jspx to another jspx page

Tags: html, jsp, jspx

I have several pages in jspx and have created a navigation.jspx. This contains links to the various pages. I am using a model view controller architecture and the normal way as shown below is not working.

```
<a href="products.jspx">View All Products</a>
```

However the code below works but once i have clicked the link twice it backtracks and i get an error message.

```
<a href="../products.jspx">View All Products</a>
```

How would i correct this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i navigate to another jspx?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403844/how-do-i-navigate-to-another-jspx)

Comment: The problem is not clear. If you're creating navigation, however, it seems like using absolute paths would be more appropriate.